# The way to configurate map position by andress

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have `GoogleMap` and configurated current position by setting:

```
CameraUpdate center=
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                        -73.98180484771729));
 mMap.moveCamera(center);
```

But this way - I need to know `Lat` and `Lng`, but I have only address.

I'm looking the way to set correct position without aditional request to getting `Lat` and `Lng`.

Answer (score 1):

So you only have the postal address of a location, but you want the Lat/Lng coordinates? Then you should check out [this API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use geocoding apis to get LatLong and then position accordingly. check out [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).
there is no direct way to do it. you can pass city name but it doesnt recognize addresses, only till city level it works and that to for specific cities only.